# TensorFlow Predicts the same probabilities for all inputs

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a model which I am using for image recognition. I am training the model to recognize three classes with between 1500-3000 images per class. I'm monitoring the cross-entropy and accuracy during training and I see them improve as the model trains. After training I reload the model and use it to predict a few additional images. In order to prove out what I'm seeing I am then using the model to predict class membership on 4 new images. One image is legitimate, one is all 0's, one it all 1's, and one is just an empty array. My data is scaled so this basically gives me an array of all 0's, one around .5's, one around 1's, and another that is near 0's. Below is my code from reloading the model and predicting the new images.

```
ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("./complex_model/")
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path + '.meta')

        x_image = tf.get_collection("x")[0]
        keep_prob = tf.get_collection("keep_prob")[0]
        batch_size_var = tf.get_collection("batch_size")[0]
        logits = tf.get_collection("logits")[0]
        y = tf.get_collection("y")[0]

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            logger.info("Model restored: {0}".format(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path))
            image, _ = ImageUtil().reformat(images, None, 3)
            image = np.concatenate((image, np.ndarray([1,60,60, 1])))
            image_names.append("no val")
            image = np.concatenate((image, np.ones([1,60,60, 1])))
            image_names.append("ones")
            image = np.concatenate((image, np.zeros([1,60,60, 1])))
            image_names.append("zeros")

            feed_dict = {x_image: image, keep_prob: 1, batch_size_var: image.shape[0]}

            prediction, logits = sess.run([y, logits], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I can see that the model being reloaded is the latest as I'm using the global step and training over thousands of iterations and it always loads the model with the correct global step appended number. However, the model predicts identical logits and probabilities for any data I feed it. Am I missing a step or overlooking something that would cause this? Below is the JSON response for class predictions and I've verified that is exactly what my sess.run is returning. I've included breakpoints during training to make sure that all images do not return the same logits during the training phase and this is not the case.

```
   "predictions": {
    "/data/predict/actual_image.jpg": [
      0.39970365166664124, 
      0.3874140679836273, 
      0.21288223564624786
    ], 
    "no val": [
      0.39970365166664124, 
      0.3874140679836273, 
      0.21288223564624786
    ], 
    "ones": [
      0.39970365166664124, 
      0.3874140679836273, 
      0.21288223564624786
    ], 
    "zeros": [
      0.39970365166664124, 
      0.3874140679836273, 
      0.21288223564624786
    ]
  },
```

I added some additional code to view my weights and I noticed an issue that all of my first layer weights are nan.

```
    variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)
    layer_1_weights = variables[0].eval() <- all nan
    layer_2_weights = variables[2].eval() <- -2 - 2
    layer_3_weights = variables[4].eval() <- -.11 - .31
    layer_4_weights = variables[6].eval() <- -.08 -.3
```

Comment: I applied gradient clipping which resolved my weights going to nan issue.